# DataFrame: cumulative sum of column until condition is reached and return sum in new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I am new in Python and am currently facing an issue I can't solve. I really hope you can help me out. English is not my native language so I am sorry if I am not able to express myself properly.

Lets suppose i have a data frame like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999], 'b':[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]})
```

I need to sum of the data in "a" until the condition "there is a value in b" is reached.
This means for the given Data Frame:

```
At index=2 there is a 1 in b --> sum rows 0+1+2 = 6666
At index=4 there is a 1 in b --> sum rows 3+4 = 9999
At index=8 there is a 1 in b --> sum rows 5+6+7+8 = 33330
```

I tried if else cases, but with no satisfactorily output..

greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(df.b.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())['a'].sum().rename_axis(None).to_frame()
print (df)
       a
0   6666
1   9999
2  33330
```

For new column use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` first and then set `0` if no match `1` in `b` by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = df.groupby(df.b.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())['a'].transform('sum')
df['cumsum'] = np.where(df.b == 1, s, 0)

print (df)
      a  b  cumsum
0  1111  0       0
1  2222  0       0
2  3333  1    6666
3  4444  0       0
4  5555  1    9999
5  6666  0       0
6  7777  0       0
7  8888  0       0
8  9999  1   33330
```

Comment: Oh great! Thanks for your fast answer! Works fine! How can I change your code to create a new column, lets say "cumsum" filled with 6666, 9999, 33330 at the position where the 1 is located in b and the origin dataframe look like the same.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I am to stupid for line breaks in comments...
Hope this is now understandable. Could the origin DataFrame be extendable by a new column "cumsum" where the `6666` `9999` and `33330` is located at the same row where the 1 is at column b?
`a  b`  
`0  1111  0`  
`1  2222  0`  
`2  3333  1`  
`3  4444  0`  
`4  5555  1`  
`5  6666  0`  
`6  7777  0`  
`7  8888  0`  
`8  9999  1`

Comment: yeah, saw and changed it ;) For future viewers: both solutions are working

Comment: Exists there also a command to get the average of the cumsumed columns? For the case above: `(1111+2222+3333)/3` or `(4444+5555)/2`?

Comment: @Klamsi - Change `sum` by `mean` function.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
df.a.groupby(df.b[::-1].cumsum()).sum()\
    .sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
```

Note that grouping is performed in **reversed order** of *b*, so looking
at this column in "forward" order, each value of *1* **terminates** the
current group.

"Post-processing" steps involve:

- reverse the order (by index),
- reset index,
- convert to a DataFrame (if you need).

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do that

```
df.merge(df.groupby(df['b'].shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())['a'].cumsum().to_frame().rename(columns={'a':'cumul_sum'}), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

and the result is

```
╭────┬──────┬─────┬─────────────╮
│    │    a │   b │   cumul_sum │
├────┼──────┼─────┼─────────────┤
│  0 │ 1111 │   0 │        1111 │
│  1 │ 2222 │   0 │        3333 │
│  2 │ 3333 │   1 │        6666 │
│  3 │ 4444 │   0 │        4444 │
│  4 │ 5555 │   1 │        9999 │
│  5 │ 6666 │   0 │        6666 │
│  6 │ 7777 │   0 │       14443 │
│  7 │ 8888 │   0 │       23331 │
│  8 │ 9999 │   1 │       33330 │
╰────┴──────┴─────┴─────────────╯
```